# PrimeFaces JS function before AJAX update/render

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have a from where I want to run a custom validate function after form processing, **but before** updating(rendering). 
If I use oncomplete obviously updating is performed before validation.
If I use onclick then validation happens before form processing which again does not suit me since I dont have the values to validate.
Is there a way to perform the function after process but before update?

```
<p:commandButton process="@form" update="@form" actionListener="#{bean.method}" oncomplete="validate()"/>
```

Comment: Do you really need to validate via Javascript? Why? JSF was designed to offer a fully integrated validation - why not use it? Why and what exactly do you want JSF to update (from server side) if validation happens via javascript (client side)? Sure there might be workarounds but it's gonna get ugly... PLEASE provide more code.

Comment: As far as I know JSF can validate individual components and not combinations. Specifically I want to check if my "startDate" component is actually before my "finishDate" component. So I actually do the check server side, then returning args to the client.

Comment: Not sure I follow but there is a work around for validating multiple components http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/multi-components-validator-in-jsf-2-0/

Comment: I agree with Andy. Considering the new info you provided in your last comment, that is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

In such cases always look into documentation. Specifically, regarding the ajax-related JavaScript functions of [`<p:commandButton>`](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.4/primefaces-p/commandButton.html), documentation states:

- *`onstart`*: Client side callback to execute before ajax request is begins;
- *`onsuccess`*: Client side callback to execute when ajax request succeeds;
- *`oncomplete`*: Client side callback to execute when ajax request is completed.

Note that there is *`onerror`* callback: Client side callback to execute when ajax request fails.

As you can understand from these excerpts, the succession of callbacks is as it is presented in the answer. Choose the one that fits your needs.

Also, it'd be wise to learn about [JSF lifecycle](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html).